# How to use order by in Laravel when it uses CASE WHEN?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can use `orderBy` method in Laravel like this:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Ok, what about when there is `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause? Like this:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN id.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN 5
   WHEN id.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 4
   WHEN id.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN 3
   WHEN id.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 2
   WHEN id.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN 1
END desc,
```

How can I write this ^ in Laravel?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
->orderByRaw(
     "CASE WHEN <CONDITION> THEN < > ELSE < > END DESC"
)
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. just for my information, will a query be matched based on the database when we use `Raw`? As you know, when you use `Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')`, it works for all databases *(just you need to change the database in the configuration)*, now I want to know, will it still work in all databases when we use `orderByRaw()` ?

Comment: No problem . I'm not sure, but I assume that it will work for all RDBMS. @stack

Answer (score 2):

You are to use `raw`, as sagi has also mentioned.

```
$posts = Post::select(DB::raw
('CASE
   WHEN id.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN 5
   WHEN id.HighCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 4
   WHEN id.HighAlertCount <> 0 THEN 3
   WHEN id.MediumCallAlertCount <> 0 THEN 2
   WHEN id.MediumAlertCount <> 0 THEN 1
END desc')
)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```