# How to make custom orderBy or DB::raw(FIELD()) with LIKE keyword and passing variable in laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have a very simple solution but I dislike that. So, How can I do?

my data base is

```
--------------------------------------
id   name   view       created_at
--------------------------------------
1   one     9      2021-01-13 12:34:22
2   two     8      2021-01-15 10:23:02
3   three   23     2021-01-15 20:55:17
4   forth   15     2021-01-16 12:34:22
5   fifth   0      2021-01-19 10:37:02
```

I want to sort and get my data like this--

```
--------------------------------------
id   name   view       created_at
--------------------------------------
5   fifth   0      2021-01-19 10:37:02
3   three   23     2021-01-15 20:55:17
4   forth   15     2021-01-16 12:34:22
1   one     9     2021-01-13 12:34:22
2   two     8     2021-01-15 10:23:02
```

My solution is

```
        $today = '2021-01-19';  //this date will calculate in daily. Not absolute date!

        $firstarray=Product::where('created_at','LIKE',$today.'%')->get();
        $secondarray=Product::orderBy('viewer', 'DESC')->get();
        $data = array_merge($firstarray,$secondarray);
        return $data;
```

**In real**, I want to make my code like this

```
    $today = '2021-01-19';  //this date will calculate in daily. Not absolute date!
    $data = Product::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(created_at, LIKE $today."%")'),'DESC')
            ->orderBy('view','desc')->get();
    return $data;
```

**How can I get powerful code for my problem?**

*Sorry for my english skill*
**thank all**

Comment: Question is not clear, do you want all results but `$today`'s to be first? Maybe `orderByRaw` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941003/how-to-use-order-by-in-laravel-when-it-uses-case-when#answer-39941031)?

Comment: Yes @Tpojka,
All of `$today` results is first and then
I want to order the remaining result by view.
The `$today` result no need to care the order by view.

Comment: Did that link help?

Comment: No, I am not clear it. I cannot solved my problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear! If it's the way I understand, that's the solution.

```
$data = Product::whereDate('created_at', now())->orderBy('view','desc')->get();
```

Comment: Your suggestion cannot solve my problem.
Your query is getting only `created_at` is meching a date and sorted `orderby('view','desc')`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need today's record first and then rest of the records ordered by view. so in this case you can order your results as

```
Product::orderByRaw("date_format(created_at ,'%Y-%m-%d') = ? desc, view desc", [$today])
         ->get();
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e692d1/6)

Comment: **Great Solution!!!**
**Work Fine!!!!**
**Thank a lot**